# Inner Join Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, tblClient and tblDB.

```
CREATE TABLE tblBD(
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
[DataBase] nVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[ClientID] INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES tblClient(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE tblClient(
[ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
[Name] nVARCHAR(30),
[Status] BIT,
[Number] INT,
)
```

I want a way to get for each client all his databases.

Something like this :

```
Client1 Client2 ClientX
BD1     BD1     BD1 
BD2     BD2     BD2
BDX     BDX     BDX
```

I can do it easily for one client by executing this script :

```
Select tblBD.[DataBase] from tblBD
inner join tblCLient on tblBD.ClientID = tblClient.ID Where tblClient.ID = 1234
```

But, I can't figure How to get the result for all clients in 1 table.

For the pivot I'm not able to get the result without using an aggregate function.

Example :

```
WITH T
AS (Select tblBD.[DataBase] as BD, tblClient.ID as ClientID from
tblBD inner join tblCLient on tblBD.ClientID = tblClient.ID)
SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT ( 
max (BD) FOR ClientID IN ([1],[2],[3], [4])
) AS pvt
```

I want to get all the databases without using an aggregate function.

Comment: You can do this with a PIVOT, but you will need either a hard-coded list of client names for headers, or dynamically generate the list with dynamic SQL or your application language.  Can you not layout the data in your application instead of the database?

Comment: The problem is that in can have n clients. So i can't harcode it. I'm Codding it in vb.net. I prefer to give to my application the entire table. I don't want to manage for each client in my application.

Comment: Yes this is a very common problem.  There should be many similar questions/solutions already on SO.

Comment: I can't really find out the perfect solution. I think that giving to my application the hole table, will save me headaches. That's why i want to just launch a query that will make the job for me.

Comment: I can get all client ID by building the string in my application. So how it's possible to make the query with pivot. Thank you.

Comment: @user1504370 Basically you'll need to use dynamic sql. I don't like writing answers with Dynamic SQL (too much work for my taste) but you can try looking at one of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+Pivot+Dynamic+Column+%5Bsql-server%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I got inspired from this :

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/pivoting-without-aggregation

Execute this script to get the number of clients:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT tblBD.ClientID) FROM tblBD
```

After create as much clients as you want.

Example with 4 clients, in my case:

```
SELECT [1] AS Client1, [2] AS Client2, [3] AS Client3, [4] AS Client4
FROM
(
    Select tblBD.[DataBase] AS BD,
    tblBD.ClientID AS ClientID ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY ClientID) AS RowNum 
    FROM tblBD
) Piv
PIVOT (MAX(BD) FOR ClientID IN ([1],[2],[3], [4])) AS pvt
```

You can build in your code a query string that will contain as many clients as you wants.